# Can i use a PiGRRL 2.0 kit with a Pi4b?

Tags: pi-4, retropie, emulation, compatibility

I'm currently wanting to put together a portable retropie or recalbox console using the raspberry pi 4b but  I'm unsure whether it is compatible with with PiGRRL kits which would be my best option.

Comment: Isn't the compatibility stated in the description when you buy the kit?

Comment: No it doesn't :-( the kit was made before the pi 4b so it doesn't state compatibility with it but it does say it's compatible with pi 2 and 3.